# how to modify array for duplicate content?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array codes like below, i want to duplicate "card" array like below. I have tried many way but i couldn't get any success. So where i supposed to put data2[i] to get result like i wanted? If you have any different solution for this i will be happy to hear that.

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $data = [
        "add_order" =>
            [
                "session_id" => "",
                "company_code" => "",
                "session" => "",
                "card" => $data2[$i] = [
                    "_key_shipping" => "",
                    "_key_customer" => ["customercode" => ""],
                ],
            ],
    ];

}

$json_send = json_encode(array($data, $data2));

file_put_contents('data.json', $json_send);
```

and its give me this result;

```
[
  {
    "add_order": {
      "session_id": "",
      "company_code": "",
      "session": "",
      "card": {
        "_key_shipping": "",
        "_key_customer": {"customercode": ""}
      }
    }
  },
  [
    {
      "_key_shipping": "",
      "_key_customer": {"customercode": ""}
    },
    {
      "_key_shipping": "",
      "_key_customer": {"customercode": ""}
    }
  ]
]
```

but i want it like this;

```
[
  {
    "add_order": {
      "session_id": "",
      "company_code": "",
      "session": "",
      "card": [{
        "_key_shipping": "",
        "_key_customer": { "customercode": ""}
      },
    {
      "_key_shipping": "",
      "_key_customer": {"customercode": ""}
    },
    {
      "_key_shipping": "",
      "_key_customer": {"customercode": ""}
    }
    
  ]
}
  }
]
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way -

```
$data = ["add_order" =>
            [
                "session_id" => "",
                "company_code" => "",
                "session" => ""
            ],
        ];

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $data["add_order"]["card"][] = [
                       "_key_shipping" => "",
                       "_key_customer" => ["customercode" => ""]   
                      ];

}

$json_send = json_encode(array($data));

file_put_contents('data.json', $json_send);
```

Comment: This is not work for me i didn't get above result what i mentioned

Comment: @imp I have edited my answer. Can you try now

Comment: i have check and try it but "card" array must below add_order array and it must be subarray. But your codes make new array for "card"

Comment: @imp sorry I misunderstood first. Now i got it. I have corrected my code.

Comment: now it's worked! Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please never post "try this" / code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  Every answer has a greater chance of being helpful to the asker and thousands of future researchers if there is a plain English explanation of the code with the intent to educate.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am new to this community. Next time I'll surely take care of it.

Comment: You are able to [edit] your answer at any time, as many times as you need, to form the best, most helpful answer that you can create.